# Query for hotel reservation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have three queries in a hotel reservation system where reserves are automatic deducted from the total number of rooms. All I want those three queries goes all in only one query. My query looks like this:

`$p =` is in a `foreach` loop where `$p['id']` is the *id* of each room class and `$p['qty']` is the maximum rooms of each room class.

```
$a = $p['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(qty) FROM prereservation where '$arrival' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
          $inogbuwin=$rows['sum(qty)'];
          }
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(qty) FROM prereservation where departure BETWEEN '$arrival' and '$departure' and room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
          $inogbuwin2=$rows['sum(qty)'];
          }
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(qty) FROM prereservation where '$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
          {
          $inogbuwin3=$rows['sum(qty)'];
          }

<select>
 <option value="0"></option>
 <? $counter = 1; ?>
 <? while ($counter <= ($p['qty'])-($inogbuwin + $inogbuwin2 + $inogbuwin3)){ ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $counter ?></option>
 <? $counter++;
 }?>
</select>
```

Every time I put a date between the range of those three queries, the total deducted is also tripled which is the reason I want those three queries to be all in one.

for example i have a record in database of 
`arrival = 27/10/2012 and departure = 29/10/2012`

and the input dates that are not available in range is

```
 $arrival = 27/10/2012 and $departure = 29/10/2012 
 $arrival = 26/10/2012 and $departure = 27/10/2012 
 $arrival = 29/10/2012 and $departure = 30/10/2012 
 $arrival = 26/10/2012 and $departure = 30/10/2012 
 $arrival = 29/10/2012 and $departure = 29/10/2012
```

so each date that in rance of those three queries are also the deductions, so i want those queries to be in one. thanks guys

after all i fixed the errors but only one preblem left. i fixed the reservation dates in only a single month, the problem is when the inputs of arrival and departure are not in the same month it does'nt work either. here's my code again below.

```
<?
$a = $p['id'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT
    SUM(IF('$arrival' BETWEEN arrival and departure, qty, 0)) AS bu1,
    SUM(IF('$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure, qty, 0)) AS bu2,
    SUM(IF(arrival > '$arrival' and departure < '$departure', qty, 0)) AS bu3
    FROM prereservation WHERE room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $test1 = $row['bu1'];
    if ($row['bu1'] == $row['bu2']){
        $test2 = $row['bu2'] - $row['bu1'];
    }else{
        $test2 = $row['bu2'];
    }       
        $test3 = $row['bu3'];
    ?>      
<select id="select" name="qty[]" style=" width:50px;" onchange="checkall()">
<option value="0"></option>
    <? $counter = 1; ?>
<? while ($counter <= ($p['qty']) - ($test1 + $test2 + $test3)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $counter ?></option>
    <? $counter++;
    }?>
```

please help me guys how to solve this reservation query, or maybe there's an other way to solve this in php code. thanks guys.

**Finally i'm finished and found the solution, here it is:**

```
            $a = $p['id'];
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id, SUM(qty)
        FROM prereservation 
        WHERE 
        (
            ( '$arival1' BETWEEN arrival AND departure ) OR 
            ( '$departure1' BETWEEN arrival AND departure ) OR 
            ( arrival > '$arival1' AND departure < '$departure1' )
        )
            AND room_id ='$a' 
            AND STATUS = 'active'");  
        while($rows1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)){
        $set1 = $rows1['SUM(qty)'];
        }   
        ?> 
        <select id="select" name="qty[]" style=" width:50px;" onchange="checkall()">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <? $counter = 1; ?>
        <? while ($counter <= ($p['qty']) - $set1){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $counter ?></option>
        <? $counter++;
        }?>
        </select>
```

**thank you guys for sharing your ideas, this solution is the combinations of your answers.. thanks again!!**

Comment: i'd tried also this query but it does'nt work.

$query = mysql_query("SELECT sum(qty) FROM prereservation where ('$arival' BETWEEN arrival and departure) and (departure BETWEEN '$arival' and '$departure') and ('$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure) and room_id ='$a' AND status = 'active'");

Comment: provide table structure, example data and the results you want.

Comment: What is `arival`? Is that a typo of arrival or are you doing some exotic naming scheme?

Comment: yes, it is the input of arrival date

Comment: Please learn about parametrized queries.  Your code is leaving you open for SQL injection attacks.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html shows you how to do parametrized queries in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF('$arrival'    BETWEEN arrival   and departure,    qty, 0)) AS bu1,
    SUM(IF(departure    BETWEEN '$arrival' and '$departure', qty, 0)) AS bu2,
    SUM(IF('$departure' BETWEEN arrival   and departure,    qty, 0)) AS bu3
FROM prereservation WHERE room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'"
```

and then in PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query(...);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$inogbuwin =$row['bu1'];
$inogbuwin2=$row['bu2'];
$inogbuwin3=$row['bu3'];
mysql_free($query);
```

*include the customary warning that* **mysql_ functions [are discouraged](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)** *and you would do well by migrating to `PDO`*

> The old API should not be used, and one day **it will be deprecated and eventually removed from PHP**. It is a popular extension so this
> will be a slow process, but you are strongly encouraged to write all
> new code with either `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL`.

Comment: there's another conflict in date when your input is $arrival = 29/10/2012 and $departure = 29/10/2012, bu1 and bu3 is deducted, how can i fix this? please help. thank you.

Comment: The simplest way would be to add an exception: `if ($arrival == $departure) { $inogbuwin++; $inogbuwin3++; }`.